# Time loop won't start with simpleFoam on openfoam

Tags: openfoam, fluid-dynamics

I started doing my first project after having done some tutorials on openfoam.
So I just did a simple Ahmed Body.Blockmesh and Snappyhexmesh are both running, I checked the mesh and it seems fine(even in Paraview). However, when I use simpleFoam, the time won't even start and I have no idea why. I used a k-omegaSST model for turbulence.
If someone have a solution or even a hint of where to look for the mistake, I'm very interested.
I can't post images, sorry for the inconvenience.
`    Create time

```
 Create mesh for time = 0


 SIMPLE: convergence criteria
      field p      tolerance 0.0001
      field U      tolerance 0.0001
      field "(k|omega|e)"  tolerance 0.0001

      Reading field p

      Reading field U

      Reading/calculating face flux field phi

       Selecting incompressible transport model Newtonian
       Selecting turbulence model type RAS
       Selecting RAS turbulence model kOmegaSST
       Selecting patchDistMethod meshWave
       bounding k, min: 0 max: 0.00109 average: 0.00109
       bounding omega, min: 0 max: 1817 average: 1817
       RAS
        {
         RASModel        kOmegaSST;
         turbulence      on;
         printCoeffs     on;
         alphaK1         0.85;
         alphaK2         1;
         alphaOmega1     0.5;
         alphaOmega2     0.856;
         gamma1          0.55555556;
         gamma2          0.44;
         beta1           0.075;
         beta2           0.0828;
         betaStar        0.09;
         a1              0.31;
         b1              1;
         c1              10;
         F3              false;
         decayControl    false;
         kInf            0;
         omegaInf        0;
         }

         No MRF models present

         No finite volume options present`
```

That's what I get when using simplefoam
edit: my controlDict file is as follow:

````
startTime       0;

stopAt          endTime;

endTime         100;

deltaT          1;

writeControl    timeStep;

writeInterval   50;

purgeWrite      0;

writeFormat     ascii;

writePrecision  8;

writeCompression off;

timeFormat      general;

timePrecision   6;

runTimeModifiable true;```
````

Comment: You mean the iterations loop, since simpleFoam is a steady-state solver. Could you share your controlDict file?

Comment: Thanks for your help, yes I meant the iterations. I edited my post and the controlDict code. i tried to look into my issue again and thought maybe as I created my project in tutorials/mesh/snappyHexMesh , simpleFoam.C can't be used but that would be strange.